# Show element if has same html and if not make an alert saying "no results"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry for the horrible title, Am terrible at wording these things.

What I am trying to do is quite simple I think.

I have a set of hidden letters that make up a word.

Below them is a selection of random jumbled up letters.

When people click one of the random jumbled letters I am filtering through the hidden letters and showing the corresponding letter.

What I need to do is, if someone clicks a letter, filter through the hidden letters and either return a "true" and show the letter or return a "false/null" and make an alert();

This is how I am filtering at the moment. I am confused as to where to place an if statement or if that is even the approach I should be taking.

And here is a fiddle (the hidden word is "Seal") - http://jsfiddle.net/GA7WB/

```
var $buttons = $('#letters span'),
    $hidden = $('.letter');

$buttons.click(function(){

    _selected = $(this).html();

    $hidden.filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == _selected;
    }).show();

});
```

Comment: If you're trying to make Hangman, ensure that a) all of the random letters are unique and b) all letters in the word to be guessed appear in the random letters.

Comment: I have more code but did not think that I needed to post that to answer the question. Would you like me to post the full code?

Comment: Yes. Always post all of the code that you have.

Comment: @MathSquared11235 Not all the code, but all the **relevant** code.

Comment: Yes I'm not sure if the way I generate the hidden word or the random letters relate to the function I am trying to do here. It would just make my problem look way bigger :-)

Comment: Just if you want it, In my version i am applying the `bold` class to the found word and also if the found word is clicked again it will not show the alert but it will show the alert for not matched ones, Like if you click first `a` from the left and than click first `a` from the right it will give alert for the `second a clicked` http://jsfiddle.net/GA7WB/5/

Comment: @KhawerZeshan thank you for this, I think I will copy this code for later when I get more into the game. I think your example is much more thought out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to check the length of the results returned by the filter:

```
// get matched elements
var matches = $hidden.filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == _selected;
});

// show them, or alert if none
if (matches.length > 0) matches.show();
else alert("There are no " + _selected + "'s");
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrSqZ/3/)

Comment: Thanks! that's just what I was trying to do. Sorry for the newb question but your if/else statement does not have any squiggly brackets. Why is this? I have always written mine like if(something){ // do something }else{ // do something else }

Comment: @ChrisG-Jones you can omit the braces if there's only a single statement -- some people might consider it bad form though.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a flag if you find one:

```
var $buttons = $('#letters span'),
var $hidden = $('.letter');

$buttons.click(function(){
    _selected = $(this).html();

    var foundOne = false;
    $hidden.filter(function() {
        var retval = $(this).text() == _selected;
        if (retval) foundOne = true;
        return retval;
    }).show();

    if (!foundOne) {
        alert("Nope");
    }
});
```

FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/GA7WB/4/